ssllab showing duplicate certs, one of them is "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate"
Our website domain was using GoDaddy as CA and AKS to host the certificates. We forgot to renew and the certificate is expired last Friday, but we have successfully generated a new one and stored it in the aks secret. All related Ingress services YAML files are correctly configured. However when we run ssllab.com test on our domain name, the "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate" is still being shown.
We have already restarted both the ingress controller and the related ingress services, but the problem persists. Ingress controller logs are not showing anything useful either. What are we missing here? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please check if you have deleted your old secret.
Sometimes, Kubernetes might still use an old or stale secret. Delete and recreating the secret.
kubectl delete secret <your-tls-secret> -n <namespace>
kubectl create secret tls <your-tls-secret> --cert=<path-to-cert> --key=<path-to-key> -n <namespace>

Sometimes the DNS or Load Balancer might cache the old certificate. Flush it using ipconfig /flushdns
(for windows) or sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
(for linux)

After that force update the Ingress by modifying the annotation
kubectl annotate ingress my-app-ingress kubernetes.io/ingress.class="nginx" --overwrite -n my-app


As suggested in comments, "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate" being shown on ssllab.com means that the old certificate is still being used by the ingress controller. Restarting the ingress controller and related ingress services should have been sufficient to pick up the new certificate, but since that did not work, you can try deleting the ingress controller pod. This will force Kubernetes to create a new pod with the updated configuration, including the new certificate.
Assuming you have an application running and you have a GoDaddy SSL Certificate handy
Store the cert in secret-
kubectl create secret tls my-tls-secret --cert=path/to/your/certificate.crt --key=path/to/your/private.key


and you have exposed the ingress controller
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - your-domain.com
    secretName: my-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: your-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-world
            port:
              number: 8080


Clear SSL Labs cache and run the SSL Labs test to verify your certificate.
Force a restart of the Ingress Controller.
kubectl delete pod -l app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx


References:

Troubleshoot Kubernetes Compute - Inference guide
Custom certificate authority (CA) in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) (preview) - Troubleshooting

